# Unable to locate persister (UnknownEntityException)

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to build a small application using Hibernate in Java.
I have prepared this code with one of the tutorials available on the internet. But it seems that is the old one.
But somehow I got stuck at this point. And not moving anywhere unless the issue is fixed. Small help will be precious.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class, hbm</property>

        <mapping class="com.test.User" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

User.java

```
package com.test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public User(int id, String name){
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

App.java

```
package com.test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Project Started...");

    try
    {
      Configuration con = new Configuration();

      con.configure().addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

      SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();

      Session session = sf.openSession();

      Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

      User u1 = new User(1, "Sunny");

      session.persist(u1);

      tx.commit();

      session.close();



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Error is here

[image]

Comment: witch version of hibernate are you using ? try to replace all imports from `javax.` to `jakarta.` Also add `@Table(name = "user_entity")` on `class User`.